# how to add the number of form by the user with php to input the data

Tags: php, forms

i m design the form to record the payment plan for project by monthly
so the user already know how long the project will spend
some project have 4 month so mean the user have to record 4 monthly payment
and some project have 8 month so mean the user have to record 8 mothly payment
what I want is the user can choose input form for record
for example if the choose 4 then the form will apprear for 4
so any suggestion the coding with php

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear but it sounds like you are trying to create a form with a multi option box for "months" selection. Here is the HTML for a drop down box which you will have to echo in your PHP.

```
<select>
  <option value="4">4 Months</option>
  <option value="8">8 Months</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @ R Ghosh i mean if user choose  4 then it will generate 4 input form to record something like dynamic form base on how many the user to put it.. thnk you

Comment: i got the answer using jQuery – Dynamically Adding Form Elements